# t.test error message " Grouping Factors Must have exactly 2 levels"

Tags: r

I am working in R markdown and trying to find out if there is a significant change in degrees and scorers before and after (PRE AND POST) an intervention for each variable.

After searching, I went to use the t. test. But I am getting and error message to saying

“Error in t.test.formula(PREOP_mLPFA ~ POSTOP_mLPFA, data = MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST, : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels”

My data sample:

PREOP_mTFA  PREOP_mLPFA PREOP_mLDFA PREOP_MPTA  PREOP_LDTA  PREOP_JLCA  PREOP_LL    PREOP_MIK
6.7 88.4    86.8    85.3    86.6    5.2     774.4   17.6
3.0 88  88  86  96  1   813 35.7
6.9 83  90.8    84.5    85.5    0.5 779.5   17.2
4.00    82  90  87  90  1   881 32

POSTOP_mTFA|    POSTOP_mLPFA|   POSTOP_mLDFA|   POSTOP_MPTA|    POSTOP_LDTA|    POSTOP_JLCA|    POSTOP_LL|  POSTOP_MIK|
0.1|    87.8|   86.1|   91.0|   85.7|   4.7|    774.9|  47.4|
0.5 88  88  90  96  1   816 47
0.3     82.6    89.8    89.9    86.8    0.5     782.9   47.2
1.90    82.0    92  90  94  0.0 874.0   41.4

Each column has over 400 observations. Both positive and negative values.

My codes is:

```
Library (tidyverse)
Library (readxl)
```

I imported the data with read_excel function and made sure all variables are typed as numerical

```
t.test(PREOP_mTFA ~ POSTOP_mTFA,
       data = MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST,
       alternative = c("two.sided"),
       mu = 0,
       paired = TRUE,
       var.equal = TRUE,
       conf.level = 0.95)
```

I have searched the literature to find solution and changed the ~ to , . But this did not work
I made sure that all the values are numerical and no empty cells, also did not work

My questions:

First, how to sort that out?

I do not understand how to make the factor 2 levels?

Second, is the t. test the correct test to find the significane of change in these degrees or scores. Any other tests to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

With the old-style interface:

```
t.test(MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST$PREOP_mTFA,
       MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST$POSTOP_mTFA, 
       paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST$PREOP_mTFA and MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST$POSTOP_mTFA
t = 3.5772, df = 3, p-value = 0.03736
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4910828 8.4089172
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   4.45
```

or with the formula interface:

```
t.test(Pair(PREOP_mTFA , POSTOP_mTFA) ~ 1 , data=MOWHTO_PARAMETERS_PREPOST)

    Paired t-test

data:  Pair(PREOP_mTFA, POSTOP_mTFA)
t = 3.5772, df = 3, p-value = 0.03736
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4910828 8.4089172
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   4.45
```

A set of paired t.tests (for each outcome) seems reasonable for this analysis.  But check the test assumptions make sure you understand the output and use the estimates and confidence intervals for interpretation not just the p-values.